# SQL - FULLTEXT INDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, full-text-catalog

I am currently trying to add a FULLTEXT Index to be able to search for key words in a narrative column which contain key words. I have tried many different tutorials and although I copy them exactly I am unable to replicate the results when using the 'CONTAINS' feature in the 'WHERE' section.

Below is a example of my script that I have been using with some example data. Would someone be able to explain to me why this is not working, as I am seriously struggling to see where the error may lie.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5
    (ID INT Identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,LOCATION VARCHAR (255)
    ,NARRATIVE VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

ALTER TABLE dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 add constraint PK_FullTextTest5 PRIMARY KEY (ID)

INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('USA Texas', 'WRIGHT BROTHERS')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Worldwide', 'CROWN PROS Builders LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Devon United Kingdom', 'J PJH ROOFING LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('UK', 'Shoreham Port Authority and Shoreham Port Developments & The Port of Shoreham Trustees ')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('EUROPE AND RUSSIA', 'ZHY SERVICES')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Austrialia', 'BrotherLimited')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('ASIA', 'DRILLING SERVICES LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('JAPAN', 'BROOKS WASTE LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Melbourne', 'TRC Service Company')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('GERMANY & HOLLAND', 'Samson Group')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Frankfurt', 'SCAFFOLDING LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Swindon, England', 'Scaffold Access Ltd')

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FullTextTest5

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (
             Location language 1033
            ,Narrative language 1033)
KEY INDEX PK_FullTextTest5 ON FullTextTest5
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO

SELECT * FROM dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 
WHERE CONTAINS(NARRATIVE, 'Access')
```

Comment: Which dbms? (This is product specific functionality....)

Comment: Can you clarify why it is not working? Any errors, or just not the results you are expecting (and if so what are they)?

Comment: There are no errors coming up when this runs. Its just there are not results being returned and I cannot understand why based on there being at least one result with the word 'Access' in it.

Comment: Hi @jarlh this is the db version if thats what you were after?
(No column name)
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
 Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx, the following appears to work properly in my local installation of SQL Server 2008 R2, as well as my local installation of SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5
    (ID INT Identity(1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,LOCATION VARCHAR (255)
    ,NARRATIVE VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_AAAA_FullTextTest5 ON dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5(ID)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('USA Texas', 'WRIGHT BROTHERS')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Worldwide', 'CROWN PROS Builders LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Devon United Kingdom', 'J PJH ROOFING LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('UK', 'Shoreham Port Authority and Shoreham Port Developments & The Port of Shoreham Trustees ')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('EUROPE AND RUSSIA', 'ZHY SERVICES')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Austrialia', 'BrotherLimited')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('ASIA', 'DRILLING SERVICES LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('JAPAN', 'BROOKS WASTE LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Melbourne', 'TRC Service Company')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('GERMANY & HOLLAND', 'Samson Group')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Frankfurt', 'SCAFFOLDING LTD')
INSERT INTO dbo.AAAA_FullTextTest5 (LOCATION, NARRATIVE) VALUES ('Swindon, England', 'Scaffold Access Ltd')
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG AAAA_FTCat;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON AAAA_FullTextTest5
(
    NARRATIVE                         --Full-text index column name 
    Language 2057                 --2057 is the LCID for British English
)
KEY INDEX UI_AAAA_FullTextTest5 ON AAAA_FTCat --Unique index
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO            --Population type;
GO
```

With the above setup in place, I can then query:

```
SELECT * FROM AAAA_FullTextTest5
WHERE CONTAINS(NARRATIVE, 'Access')
```

And get this result set:

```
ID    LOCATION            NARRATIVE
12    Swindon, England    Scaffold Access Ltd
```

Comment: Hi Paul

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this still doesn't seem to be working for 2012.

Comment: @bwsutton Are you sure you've copied the code properly?  I can run this against my local copy of SQL Server 2012 with the same result set as well.

Comment: Hi Paul

Yes I am sure that I have copied it correctly and just had my colleague shadow me to check. I tried a couple of times now and still get 0 rows back unfortunately.

Comment: @bwsutton Well, color me stumped.  I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.  If the fulltext index is created successfully, the SELECT query always returns the expected results on my machine.  I don't believe there is even a way to disable full-text search on a table once a fulltext index has been created for it.  If languages or wordbreaks weren't installed, you'd get an error creating the index.  I am out of ideas  as to how you could create the index successfully but have the query return no results.

Comment: I know it is very confusing. I have checked the install configuration and all seems to be ok which is why the index is running as you have stated.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps @Paul-Griffin but I have just checked the View Facets of the FullText Catalogs to which is reads Count: 0. I'm not sure if this highlights an issue?